# Architecture ideas for multiple plugable payment systems in one application?

Tags: architecture, payment, system

We have been developing an e-commerce application for a year now and we started doing business in different countries. This means having to implement a number of very different payment systems inside a single application. For example we have different types of credit card processor gateways for each country, mobile payment gateways in some countries, pay pal, direct banking in each country and so on ... Each of these systems is designed in its own way with its own data model and sometimes its own workflow and we use different subgroups of these payment systems in different countries. There is a great need to make this plugable. However we have no experience with such architecture. Since we started by adding one by one as the need arose, we currently have no real architecture for this, as we have only one table in database and this single table contains all the fields for all the payment systems we support, which is becoming very error prone and chaotic.

What do you think is the best solution to create a truly plugable system for all of these different payment options each with its own data model but completely pluggable?

Comment: We went with SOA for our payment services. Works out nicely.

Comment: @ChrisKlepeis, SOA is a generic answer to the issue. I'm curious as to how you were able to resolve this (more specifically). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A common approach to this is to bundle the payment functionalities into separate modules. A module exposes two main methods towards the business logic:

- `reserve()` to reserve a credit for a limited time, i.e. to probe if the payment transaction would be successful.
- `commit()` to trigger the actual money flow as reserved previously.

The business logic would

1. `reserve()` a payment before performing the to-be-paid activity
2. perform the activity (e.g. deliver content,...)
3. `commit()` the payment

Most payment systems should fit into this scheme.

On top of this one would need a plugin mechanism in order to dispatch to the correct payment module based on user information.